# jenkins. passing vm options for job (using placeholder)

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, configuration, jenkins

**Hi all**

I use SpringPlaceholderConfig.
In **config.properties** file I have placeholder like `dbSchemaName = ${schema}`

And in the **context.xml** `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://url:port/${dbSchemaName}"/>`

all works fine if I pass VM option in local tomcat server through Idea

[Idea Tomcat config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p91hz.png)

But running the application on Jenkins + Tomcat causes exception like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'schema' in string value "${schema}"
```

This is Job config (VM options)

[Jenkins job config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVjFC.png)

I want to pass different values of arguments for different jobs. So I need to save this values in scope of each job. I know that it possible, but I don't know how? How can I make it without using global Jenkins config and *catalina.sh* etc...

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Jenkins+Tomcat+Maven.
As you can see in attach (with Jenkins config) I tried to pass VM options in Maven build section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with SpringPlaceholderConfig is that it evaluates stuff at runtime. The variable you're setting in Jenkins will only live during the maven build.

What you should do, is to enable resource filtering:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

It will process all the files in the mentioned directory and will look for placeholders. Then it will replace all of the placeholders in the files with actual values. So in your actual build files will not have placeholders, but actual values. This way when you specify `-Dschema=spd` maven will replace `${schema}` placeholders in your configuration files with `spd` and the resulting config file will be there in the output jar/war file. This basically allows to specify your environment during build time and the build will be tied to environment.

More reading: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html